# BitcoinCore Ubuntu buiild error: ‘relative’ is not a member of ‘fs’

Tags: bitcoin-core, client, ubuntu, compiling, make

I'm trying to build [Bitcoin core client](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin) on an LinuxMint. I'm having the following error(which have not encountered before, while making it on MSWindows or another Linux machine) in make process, right after

```
CXX      wallet/libbitcoin_wallet_a-walletutil.o
```

& I can't figure out why:

```
wallet/walletutil.cpp: In function ‘std::vector<boost::filesystem::path> ListWalletDir()’:
wallet/walletutil.cpp:60:32: error: ‘relative’ is not a member of ‘fs’
         paths.emplace_back(fs::relative(it->path(), wallet_dir));
                            ^
wallet/walletutil.cpp:71:36: error: ‘relative’ is not a member of ‘fs’
             paths.emplace_back(fs::relative(it->path(), wallet_dir));
Makefile:6894: recipe for target 'wallet/libbitcoin_wallet_a-walletutil.o' failed
make[2]: *** [wallet/libbitcoin_wallet_a-walletutil.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/behrad/cprj/bitcoin/src'
Makefile:10232: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/behrad/cprj/bitcoin/src'
Makefile:774: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

My machine version is `uname -a` output:

```
Linux anonymous 4.10.0-38-generic #42~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 10 16:32:20 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

One thing comes to my mind is the initial advice on `build-unix.md` doc, which was warning against relative paths:

```
Always use absolute paths to configure and compile Bitcoin Core and the dependencies, for example, when specifying the path of the dependency:

    ../dist/configure --enable-cxx --disable-shared --with-pic --prefix=$BDB_PREFIX

Here BDB_PREFIX must be an absolute path - it is defined using $(pwd) which ensures the usage of the absolute path.
```

But as I stated, I've passed configuration & this occurred while it was about finishing. I can installing w/o wallet, but I need it in this installation. Thank you for taking time reading so far, Any help appreciated in advance.

Comment: Looks like your version of Boost Filesystem is too old. Read doc/build-unix.md in the repository for instructions on what packages to use. Did that help?

Comment: Thank you Mr Wuille (@PieterWuille) for following up! Yeah, I've closely followed the steps (As I do always w/ bitcoincore installation), But this is weired! Unfortunately I'm not sure enough if its a public issue so I can post it as an issue w/ steps for recreation to help you find out more about my env.